# select last cell of last row in kendo ui scheduler

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, scheduler

I have a kendo ui scheduler and my requirement is when user hits end key press the last cell of last row must be selected of  kendo ui scheduler please help me how to achive this any help or advice would be valuable for me.

Comment: $('#yourScheduler .k-scheduler-table tr:last-child td:last-child').addClass('k-state-selected');

Comment: its apply only property of class not seleted i use this class alredy.

Comment: please let me know how to find uid of last cell of last row

Comment: $('#yourScheduler .k-scheduler-table tr:last-child td:last-child').select(uid ) its working or not i am just asking to you. thanks for support.

Comment: no according to the docu it should be $("#yourScheduler").data("kendoScheduler").select(uid);

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-select

Comment: then how can i select last cell of last row by end key press..

Comment: how to find uid please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 35) {
        var scheduler = $("#yourScheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
        var element = scheduler.view().content.find("tr:last td:last");
        var slot = scheduler.slotByElement(element);
        scheduler.select(slot);
    }               
});
```